# Multiple wildcards with asPercent in Graphite

Tags: monitoring, graphite, grafana

I have multiple series for `stats.counters.app.view.isbn.fetch.found.{yes,no}.$service`. I want to calculate the failure rate per `$service`.

- **`#A`** `reduceSeries(mapSeries(group(#B, #C), 0), 'asPercent', 1, 'none', 'total')`
- **`#B`** `aliasSub(groupByNode(stats.counters.app.view.isbn.fetch.found.*.*.rate, 8, "sumSeries"), "^(.*)$", "\1.total")`
- **`#C`** `aliasSub(groupByNode(stats.counters.app.view.isbn.fetch.found.no.*.rate, 8, "sumSeries"), "^(.*)$", "\1.none")`

However, this results in an error. From all possible variants I tried, this one feels the most correct, but it still fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it. It can be solved using `groupByNode`.

- **`#A`** `groupByNode(group(#B, #C), 0, 'asPercent')`
- **`#B`** `aliasSub(groupByNode(stats.counters.app.view.isbn.fetch.found.yes.*.rate, 8, "sumSeries"), "^(.*)$", "\1.yes")`
- **`#C`** `aliasSub(groupByNode(stats.counters.app.view.isbn.fetch.found.no.*.rate, 8, "sumSeries"), "^(.*)$", "\1.no")`